# Accessing to Request object will lead to ReadEntityBody to return 0 (in a HttpHandler class)

Tags: asp.net

I created a httpHandler that successfully implements IHttpHandler for handling file uploads. It works perfectly fine. You send the file with the form, the class receives it and will save it to hard disk. It reads chunks of file with ReadEntityBody function of HttpWorkerRequest class.

Here is the situation i'm faced with.If at any stage before trying to read the file with ReadEntityBody, I try to access Request object (even Request.InputStream.Length!) ReadEntityBody would return 0 means it won't read from file stream.

After further testing I found out the reason behind it. **Accessing to `Context.Current.Request` object will trigger some sort of functionality that will cause asp.net to handle file uploads at that moment by it's own!** I believe this is a bug.

for example exactly after this line of code, asp.net will upload the file completely, and so there will be no stream for ReadEntityBody to read from later.

```
int FileSize = context.Request.InputStream.Length;
```

Can anybody tell how to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont "upload" the file. The file is already uploaded regardless. The way I understand it is that Accessing Request object will cause it to read out request data into `Request.Form`, `Request.Files`, etc. 
Obvious thing to try would be to set `Request.InputStream.Position = 0` before calling your chunked read methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that but you are wrong. as I described it hasn't been uploaded. uploading file is the job of httpHandler, that's why they call it httpHandler.

I describe an example here, I remote debugged the project, I tried to upload a 100mb file, at the moment I press the submit button the first break point on my code will be called immediately. means that file hasn't been uploaded yet but after that line of code I mentioned above there will be an unlimited pause, till the asp uploads the file and then code continues. I know... it's pretty strange but true.

Comment: No I was confused... Of course it doesn't work. The `InputStream` is pointing to already preloaded data. The main idea is the same though. When you access Request object it does exactly the same thing you do - reads from worker request. The worker request seem to be forward-only, so the data that has been read is gone, so it is no wonder you get nothing. Now the real question is what exactly are you trying to do and why is this a problem?